# Rendering without breaking encapsulation

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, rendering, encapsulation

What is the proper way to implement this without breaking encapsulation? I kept the example simple but the solution should scale well if I should decide to add more entities. I have a student and courses like so:

```
class Student {

    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
     * Courses student is attending
     * @var Course[]
     */
    private $courses = array();
    private $numberOfAttendingCourses;

}

class Course {

    private $code;

}
```

Let's say I'd like to render this:

```
<ul>
    <li>[studentName] ([numberOfAttendingCourses])</li>
</ul>
```

and also this is the view in another use case

```
<ul>
    <li>[studentName] (ID: [studentId])
        <ul>
            <li>[course1Name] ([course1Code])</li>
            <li>[course2Name] ([course2Code])</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I know how to implementing this with getters and setters. I'm interested in the way which keeps both objects encapsulated as much as possible.

Comment: There is nothing about getters and setters that would "break encapsulation". Any solution wherein nothing is left out of the class which really ought to be a part of the object "encapsulates". Asking what strategy encapsulates more or less is not as relevant as asking _how_ you would like these objects to interact. It seems very much like there is something more you are looking for here. What is your goal? How do you want this encapsulation to serve the greater needs of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to pass off value structure to your template renderer. This will keep you from being tempted to doing too much logic within the template itself.

For example - First off create an interface for your renderable classes

```
class Renderable {
     public function getViewData();
}
```

Then make your student and Course classes conform to the interface .

```
class Student implements Renderable{

    private $id;
    private $name;

    /**
     * Courses student is attending
     * @var Course[]
     */
    private $courses = array();
    private $numberOfAttendingCourses;
    public function getViewData(){
        $dat = array("id"=>$this->id, "name"=>$this->name, "courses"=>array());
        foreach($this->courses as $course){
            $dat["courses"][] = $course->getViewData();
        }
        $dat["numCourses"] = count($dat["courses"]);
        return $dat;
    }

}

class Course implements Renderable{

    private $code;
    private $name;

    public function fetchViewData(){
        return array("code"=>$this->code,
                     "name"=>$this->name);
    }
}
```

The create a template parser.

```
class Template {
     public function render($templateFile, array $data){
          if ($data instanceof Renderable){
               $data = $data->getViewData();
          }
          extract ($data);
          ob_start();
          include($templateFile);
          ob_get_clean();
     }
}
```

Then a simple template for your markup

```
<ul>
    <li><?= htmlspecialchars($name) ?> (ID: <?= htmlspecialchars($id) ?>)
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($courses as $course): ?>
            <li><?= htmlspecialchars($course["code"]) ?> (<?= htmlspecialchars($course["code"]) ?>)</li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then once you have a valid Student object you can simply

```
$template = new Template();
$template->render("/path/to/template.phtml", $student->fetchViewData());
```

This should also make it very simple for you to develop and test your templates as you would be able to use a serviceable array instead of going and creating a Student and a bunch of Course objects.

Comment: Elegant. Could the same technique be used for storing those objects in the db?

Comment: @namesnik I don't see why not.

Comment: Why do you do `if (!is_array($data)){`, when you can enforce this to be an array, like this `render($templateFile, array $data)`??

Comment: And also, your `class Student {}` violates the `POLS` : Both setters and setters should do only singular task : Assign and return values and only. It would make sense to rename `getViewData(){` to `fetchViewData()` to satisfy the `POLS`.

Comment: @DaveJust Both well informed design improvements, adjusted my answer to reflect both.